# Unknown column in field list on insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with a primary column "MatchId", followed by many other columns.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get my insert/update query right: Even if I only want to insert an MatchId (Not auto-increment by the way), I get the error Unknown column in 'field list'...

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO `stats` (`MatchId`) VALUES (`123456`);
```

How do I insert something in this table without getting this error?

Comment: show the full schema of your table `stats`

Comment: Try VALUES ('123456') (single quotes) in place of VALUES (`123456`) ?

Comment: @Fred -ii- I believe that my question is not a duplicate, since I did not explicitely *know* that my problem had to do with backticks (As stated in my original question, I read about backticks etc on stackoverflow, but none of the answers helped me.)

Comment: So, why did you accept Barmar's answer then if you feel that it's not a duplicate?

Comment: @Fred -ii- As I said, at the time that I created this question I had already tried solutions from other SO questions, but they didnt seem to work for me (Also, I did not know what the problem actually was - Being anout quotes was just a hunch). Barmar answered to my specific problem and made me undrstand why things are like they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong types of quotes around the value. Backticks are used around table and column names. To quote a string, use single or double quotes:

```
INSERT INTO `stats` (`MatchId`) VALUES ('123456');
```

If it's an integer, you don't need to quote it at all:

```
INSERT INTO `stats` (`MatchId`) VALUES (123456);
```

Putting a value in backticks forces it to be treated as a column name, even though it has the syntax of a number. Backticks are the way that MySQL allows you to use column names that have unusual syntax.

Comment: Weird, now it works. I don't understand why though: 123456 is an integer, not a string - So why should it be treated like one?

Comment: In your original code you were making it a column name by putting it in backticks.

Answer (score 1):

Test it in phpmyadmin the unrecognised field is "123456". Change your SQL and wrap the value in single quotes